# CSS Overflow whitespace text

Tags: css

Basically I am trying out CSS trying to create a chat box for some reason when I `float:right` the chat message it goes out of the chat box but I when I `float:left` it works fine as it should be here is the JS Fiddle which shows the problem!

https://jsfiddle.net/g8ax21aa/

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h4,
h5 {
  line-height: 3.0em;
  margin: 0;
}

hr {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* For IE 6/7 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* ---------- LIVE-CHAT ---------- */

#live-chat {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  right: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

#live-chat header {
  background: #293239;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}

#live-chat h4:before {
  background: #1a8a34;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 8px;
}

#live-chat h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#live-chat h5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#live-chat form {
  padding: 24px;
}

#live-chat input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
  width: 234px;
}

.chat-message-counter {
  background: #e62727;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.chat-close {
  background: #1b2126;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
}

.chat {
  background: #fff;
}

.chat-history {
  height: 252px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-message {
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.chat-message img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.chat-time {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.user {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4080ff;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
}

.server {
  background-color: #f1f0f0;
  color: #4b4f56;
  margin-left: 15px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

.msg {
  overflow-wrap: inherit;
  text-shadow: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 8px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}
```

```html
<div id="live-chat">

  <header class="clearfix">

    <a href="#" class="chat-close">x</a>

    <h4>LOG</h4>

  </header>

  <div class="chat">

    <div class="chat-history">

      <div class="chat-message clearfix">


        <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

          <span class="chat-time">13:35</span>
          <span class="msg user">aslkdsakdhsalkdsakldhsalkdhklashdklsahdklhsakldhklashkldaskdlkklsaskldklsad!.</span>

        </div>

      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="chat-message clearfix">

        <img src="./imgs/u1.png" alt="" width="32" height="32">

        <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

          <span class="chat-time">13:37</span>

          <h5>UROA</h5>

          <span class="msg server">HIasklhdlksahdklsahdklashdlkhadlkahkdhlsahdhkalkdhsahldkahlkdlkaslkdhkaskhldkla!</span>

        </div>

      </div>
      <hr>

    </div>
    <form id="chat_form">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type your message…" autofocus>
        <input type="hidden">
      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: use word-break: break-word;

Comment: word-break does not work just tried.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g8ax21aa/1/

Comment: See the blue text it's not breaking.

Comment: I see that everything is fine.

Comment: @curveball Seems like OP is using Firefox or something. Just tried FF and it doesn't break the word. So far I've tested in Chrome and it works.

Comment: Yea I am using Firefox, lemme try Chrome any solution for Firefox?

Comment: @Premt how about this one? Works on FF as well: https://jsfiddle.net/g8ax21aa/3/ - `word-break: break-all;`.

Comment: Awesome it works!, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.msg {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

seems to be the way to go. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

PS. It turns out that `break-word` is an unofficial value for `word-break` property and it should be `break-all`. From [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=word-break):

> Partial support (CSS3 word-break property) refers to supporting the break-all value, but not the keep-all value. **Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink** browsers also **support the unofficial break-word** value which is treated like word-wrap: break-word.

So, you are better off using `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score 0):

See my code below. I added `word-break: break-word;` 
and it works fine.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h4,
h5 {
  line-height: 3.0em;
  margin: 0;
}

hr {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* For IE 6/7 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* ---------- LIVE-CHAT ---------- */

#live-chat {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  right: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

#live-chat header {
  background: #293239;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}

#live-chat h4:before {
  background: #1a8a34;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 8px;
}

#live-chat h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#live-chat h5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#live-chat form {
  padding: 24px;
}

#live-chat input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
  width: 234px;
}

.chat-message-counter {
  background: #e62727;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.chat-close {
  background: #1b2126;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
}

.chat {
  background: #fff;
}

.chat-history {
  height: 252px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-message {
  margin: 16px 0;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.chat-message img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.chat-time {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.user {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4080ff;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
}

.server {
  background-color: #f1f0f0;
  color: #4b4f56;
  margin-left: 15px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

.msg {
  overflow-wrap: inherit;
  text-shadow: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 8px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}
```

```html
<div id="live-chat">

  <header class="clearfix">

    <a href="#" class="chat-close">x</a>

    <h4>LOG</h4>

  </header>

  <div class="chat">

    <div class="chat-history">

      <div class="chat-message clearfix">


        <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

          <span class="chat-time">13:35</span>
          <span class="msg user">aslkdsakdhsalkdsakldhsalkdhklashdklsahdklhsakldhklashkldaskdlkklsaskldklsad!.</span>

        </div>

      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="chat-message clearfix">

        <img src="./imgs/u1.png" alt="" width="32" height="32">

        <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

          <span class="chat-time">13:37</span>

          <h5>UROA</h5>

          <span class="msg server">HIasklhdlksahdklsahdklashdlkhadlkahkdhlsahdhkalkdhsahldkahlkdlkaslkdhkaskhldkla!</span>

        </div>

      </div>
      <hr>

    </div>
    <form id="chat_form">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type your message…" autofocus>
        <input type="hidden">
      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
 .msg {

    width:256px; // add this 
    word-wrap:break-word;// add this
    ...//your code
}
```

[Demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhzpn098/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in real life there are no words with that size of characters

try this:

```
width: 100%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```